# Winsock error 10014 when trying to use a socket in Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, sockets

The problematic section of code looks roughly as follows:

```
import socket, my_custom_socket_address_getting_module

underlyingSocketFileno = my_custom_socket_address_getting_module.get()
connectedSocket = socket.socket( fileno=underlyingSocketFileno )
clientAddress = connectedSocket.getpeername()
```

Where "my_custom_socket_address_getting_module" is a custom C extension which returns the address of an open socket on my machine (as a long).

The first two lines seem to work well, and the Python socket object looks sensible (e.g. the `fd` and other socket properties look correct in the debugger), but trying to call `getpeername` on the object throws the following exception:

```
<class 'OSError'>:[WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call
```

Since I'm letting Python construct both the Python socket (and presumably the backing OS `SOCKET` as well), I've no idea where the broken pointer address would be coming from.

I'm fairly confident that the socket address being supplied to Python from my custom module is correct, and that the socket address it returns is valid, as the extension worked perfectly with my old Python version.

This issue started when I moved to a much more recent version of Python (3.6.5) - any ideas as to why this new version would be acting like this? 
The previous working version was Python 1.5.2 (yes, really).

(OS is Microsoft Windows 8.1 64, Python 3.6.5, built with MSVCC v.1911)

Comment: What was the old Python version which worked? Please add it to the bug. To debug the problem, you may want to try it with all Python versions in-between, and when you figure out which version broke it, ask specifically on a Python mailing list, to talk with the developers.

Comment: You should specify which version your were using earlier as well.

Comment: @pts I agree that that's what I'll end up having to do if I find no more promising leads. Unfortunately the previous working version was Python 1.5.2, so there's a fair amount of ground to cover.

Comment: I'd try 2.0.1 (https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.0.1/), then 2.7.14 (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/). If only 2.0.1 works, then it's possible to bisect: try the latest 2.4 etc.

Comment: Unless you are very lucky to have a StackOverflow user or Python mailing list user know the answer from the top of their head, you may have to do tedious work of trying multiple Python versions.

Comment: What does "returns the socket address of an open socket" mean, what is the C type of the value returned?

Comment: Did you perhaps move from 32-bit Python (1.5.2) to 64-bit Python (3.6.5)?

Comment: Did you try to reset winsock? `netsh winsock reset` in the terminal

Comment: What are the family and type of the socket?

Comment: Assuming IPv6 is enabled in the OS, I would check if Python was built with IPv6 support by checking `socket.has_ipv6`. If not then Python is being sent an IPv6 address in a `sock_addr` which is too small (a `sock_addr_storage` is larger and would be suitable). Python 1.5.2 is working because the buffer is defined as `char addrbuf[256]` which is plenty of space to receive an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Python 3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html) for the `socket.socket` constructor:

> If fileno is specified, the other arguments are ignored, causing the socket with the specified file descriptor to return.

Maybe this was obvious to the author of the documentation, but it looks like this only works if the socket associated with the `fileno` you pass in was created by Python. If you are trying to connect to a socket which was opened by an extension module, then Python will create a `socket` object with the `fileno` you gave it, but the other socket properties (type, family, protocol) will be set to their default values.

In this case, the socket was an IPv6 socket, but the default for Python sockets is IPv4. Manually specifying the socket type and family resolved the issue.

Comment: "the other socket properties (type, family, protocol) will be set to their default values": this has changed in Python 3.7 https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/52a5a17338dfa7fed259027e1ecceba9c8491189/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4864

Comment: Benjamin, can you share the way in which you have discovered that? The answer itself is really cool, but readers might also learn from your chain of hypothesis and checks.

Comment: @void: Ben discovered the problem by examining the Python source code for socket creation.  (I work with Ben; I'm not psychic. :-)